# Ordered resolution of types from Castle Windsor AllTypes

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a group of classes that implement an interface for my application start-up activities. Here is the registration code:

```
private static void ConfigureContainer()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Register(AllTypes.Of<IStartupTask>()
             .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    ...

    var serviceLocator = container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>();
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
}
```

In order to get the tasks, I use this and it works as expected:

```
public static void Run()
{
    var tasks = ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IStartupTask>();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
       task.Execute();
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: I have one task that depends on another being run first. There is an `InitializeDatabase` task that needs to run before the `PopulateDatabse` task. There are also a bunch of other tasks that are run and I would rather not split the `InitializeDatabase` task out, if there is some Castle config that will allow me to order the resolution of the types. I don't want to specify the complete order of the types being resolved since that defeats the purpose of the automatic registration, just that `InitializeDatabase` is the first or `PopulateDatabase` is last.

Is there a way to register which types should be resolved first without specifying the order of all the types?

Comment: Why are you using the Common Service Locator?

Comment: I was experimenting with some other tools and haven't taken it out yet. I copied the snippets from my code and didn't want to make a mistake with the Castle syntax in the question. 

Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, it might not be very pretty but it works:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class FirstAttribute: Attribute {}
public interface IService {}
public class ThirdService : IService { }
[First]
public class FirstService : IService { }
public class SecondService: IService {}

[Test]
public void WindsorOrder() {
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Register(AllTypes.Of<IService>()
        .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

    var intf = container.ResolveAll<IService>()
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FirstAttribute), true).Length)
        .ToArray();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(FirstService), intf[0]);
}
```

If you remove `[First]` from `FirstService`, the first will be `ThirdService` and the test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use HandlerSelector for that

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I looked at HandlerSelector but I didn't see how I could use it for this case. HandlerSelector.SelectHandler() is called for every implementation of IStartupTask, so I'm not sure how to order the service resolutions from there. Am I using HandleSelector wrong?